# Proof a sequence converges to a limit

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

For a sequence

$$a_n = \frac{\sin(n)+2}{4n^2-28}$$

How would you use the definition of a limit of a sequence to prove $a_n$ converges to $0$

I am really stuck with how this definition works, I understand you need to find a value for $N>$ but all examples end up with a min/max answer and I have no idea how they got there.

Why is the answer $\min\{5,1/\sqrt{\varepsilon}\}$?

When I look online I can only find examples using the definition of convergence of a function and not sequence.

What are the rules for cancelling down when and how and why do you get min/max  answers?

Really looking for a step by step answer thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|a_n - l |= \left|{\frac{\sin(n)+2}{4n^2-28}}\right|  = \frac{|\sin(n)+2|}{4|n-\sqrt 7||n + \sqrt 7|}$$

Now $n\ge 4 \implies n - \sqrt 7 \gt 1$. Therefore,

$$|a_n - l | \lt  \frac{|\sin(n)+2|}{4|n + \sqrt 7|} \le  \frac{|\sin(n)| +2}{4(n + \sqrt 7)}    \le  \frac{3}{4n }$$

Now let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be an arbitrary natural number.  Since $\Bbb N$ is unbounded there must be a natural number, $N$, which is greater than $\text{Min} \{ \frac{3}{4\epsilon}, 4 \}$. Then,

$$n \ge N \implies |a_n - l| \lt \frac{3}{4n } \le \frac{3}{4N }  \lt \epsilon \implies \lim(a_n) = l = 0 $$

---

I thought of explaining all of this a little bit more. When you are asked to prove the convergence of a sequence what you need to do is to make the quantity $|a_n - l|$ as small as possible($l$ is the limit here). The best way to do this is to show that it is smaller than $\frac{A}{n}$ where $A \gt 0$ and $n$ is a positive number. This quantity can be made as small as you wish by choosing $n$ as large as required. To do this you need to use inequalities. What we have done here is show that the denominator and numerator of $|a_n - l|$ can be approximated using other fractions. For an example if $|4n^2 - 28| \gt n^2 $, then $ \frac{|\sin n + 2|}{|4n^2 - 28|} \lt \frac{|\sin n + 2|}{n^2 } $. And you use similar steps to get to a point where you can say that if $n$ is large enough then |$a_n - l|$ is as small you want i.e. is less than any $\epsilon \gt 0$, however small. Now, according to your answer if we choose $n$ such that $n \gt \min\{5,1/\sqrt{\varepsilon}\} $ then you must see that $ \frac{1}{n^2} \lt \epsilon \; $ **and** $4n^2 - 28 \gt n^2$ satissfying both our conditions. And we are done.

Comment: In the answer I have it says that $n^2>28$ therefore $n>5$

Comment: That sounds wrong. What it might say is $n \gt 5$ and therefore $n^2 \gt 28$. Which is fine. Now use $4n^2 - 28 = 3n^2 + n^2 - 28 \gt 3n^2 \gt n^2$. Now choose $N$ as you have stipulated in your question. But remember this is a proof. There is no **answer**. You can give your own proof. As long as it is valid any self-respecting teacher will accept it.

Comment: would it not actually be Max?

Comment: Correct! Was blindly thrown off. Confused between limit of a sequence and function. Max it is.

Comment: One last question currently doing $3n^2+5n+9$/$2n^2+1$ coverging to $3/2$ and I get to $10n+15/4n^2+2$ I was wondering what I do in this situation as I don't see how I can make it bigger? and its complicated by the fact theres a n and n^2, sorry to ask man, these proofs are just really killing me.

Comment: $$ \frac{10n + 15}{4n^2 + 2} \lt \frac{10n + 15}{4n^2} \le \frac{10n + 15n}{4n^2} = \frac{25}{ 4n }   $$

Comment: cheers man, life saver

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems pretty straightforward to me, so I wonder if I am missing something.  Wouldn't be the first time.  But anyway ...

$\sin(n)$ can never be greater than 1 or less than -1.  Therefore the numerator, whatever its value for any particular $n$, is always less than or equal to 3 (i.e. 1+2) and greater than or equal to 1 (i.e. -1+2).  The sequence $3/(4n^2 - 28)$ and the sequence $1/(4n^2-28)$ both converge to zero for $n\rightarrow\infty$, because the denominator grows toward infinity.  The limit of your given sequence must lie in between these two limits, i.e. between zero and zero, and must therefore go to zero.

Comment: Yes it obviously converges to zero, but I need to show it does using the definition of a limit of a sequence

Answer (score 0):

Fix $\epsilon >0$. Now you should try to find a positive integer $N$ such that, whenever $n >N$, you get $|a_n|<0$. Since you already know the answer, you should deduce that the sequence shows some decreasing pattern for $n>5$ (this probably comes from the factor $4n^2-28$ which is positive for $n\geq 5$, $n$ integer positive.

Also, note that $|sin(n)|\leq 1$ for all $n$. I would also try using triangle inequality on $|sin(n)+2|$. The standard approach here is to compare $|a_n|$ with some arbitrary positive $\epsilon$ and get some information on $\epsilon$.

Comment: why must n be greater than 5

Comment: as its $4n^2$ couldn't it be just greater than 3?

Comment: Hmm right. But the number 5 was taken probably for safety.

Comment: It doesn't change the idea. You just have to show that for $n$ large enough you have $|a_n|<\epsilon$.